# New to python, getting ValueError in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I'm trying to make graphs with shading for my math assignment, but keep getting this error. I'm really new to python and coding (used it for two days) and know this error is due to a stretched array or something. 
This is the error and code:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,) (894,)

Error happens in line 47, ax1.fill_between(y2, d1)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#Needs a fig if you want to shade


fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots()


#Graph limits
plt.xlim(-50, 550)
plt.ylim(2800,4300)



#Cost 1 - Function 1, variable t
t = np.arange(1000)
t1 = 28 * t + 78652 / t
plt.plot(t1)


#Cost 2a <106 - Function 2, variable g
g = np.arange(0,106)
g1 = 3 * g + 3392
plt.plot(g1)

#Cost 2b >106 - Function 3, variable d
d = np.arange(106,1000)
d1 = 3 * d + 3392

#Cost2b - Shading
line1 = ax1.plot()
ax1.fill_between(d, d1)

#Revenue <200 - Function 4, variable y and y2 (I think)
f = lambda c1,a : (a * c1) / 150
a = 1
c1 = np.linspace(0, 200)
y = f(c1,a)
y2 = 200 * np.log(y) + 4000
ac1 = plt.plot(c1, y2)

#Shading

line1 = ax1.plot()
ax1.fill_between(y2, d1)




#Revenue >200 - Function 4, variable y and y2 (I think)
f = lambda c2,a : (a * c2) / 150
a = 1
c2 = np.linspace(200, 400)
y = f(c2,a)
y2 = 200 * np.log(y) + 4000
ac2 = plt.plot(c2, y2)

#Show the plot on a graph
plt.show()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is not a matplotlib-related question. A good practice is to try to split your code into its fundamental parts and check them separately. This will help you find the bug and ask a clean question. Your problem is a mismatch in the shape of arrays defined in lines 29 and 39. I will flag your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your items have different shapes.. Just do the following:
`c1 = np.linspace(0, 200, 894)'

This will specify the length of `y` as similar to `d`.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding 894 to linspace worked which is great but when I made y = np.arange(0,894), the log graph goes straight up and doesn't shade. Sorry its probably really frustrating dealing with me but I appreciate the help!